# Obtaining full requested url address

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to obtain the full requested url within python/django. I'm wondering what package might help me do this.

For example, if someone goes to example.com/my-homepage, I want to capture the string 'example.com/my-homepage' in python.

Thanks!

Comment: you should provide more details about the framework you are using. Is it Django, Flask or something else?

Comment: its Django. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
host = request.build_absolute_uri()
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri

Comment: maybe https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path `get_full_path` to not include the protocol?

Comment: request.build_absolute_uri() works. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

try `request.path`

more details [here] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#attributes)